# JFrame repaint() and revalidate() only updating when window is resized on Mac os

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe, repaint

I use this class for my school app projects. It is how I set the application up and it extends JFrame and implements Runnable. Now whenever I use this in school on a Windows computer and everything works and the screen updates, but at home on a Mac it doesn't. I use Eclipse neon with JDK 1.8.0_101 
Please help me out, I can't test any projects at home cause of this.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public abstract class GUIApplication extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private Screen currentScreen;
    //no main, cant instentiate an abstract class
    public GUIApplication(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int x=40;
        int y=40;
        int width=1000;
        int height=640;
        setBounds(x,y,width,height);
        initScreen();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    //this is a method for creating the starting screen
    protected abstract void initScreen();

    public void setScreen(Screen screen){
        //stop controls from previous screen
        removeListeners();

        setCurrentScreen(screen);
        //add new controls
        addListeners();
    }

    private void removeListeners(){
        if(getCurrentScreen() != null){
            if(getCurrentScreen().getMouseListener() != null)     removeMouseListener(getCurrentScreen().getMouseListener());
            if(getCurrentScreen().getMouseMotionListener() != null) removeMouseMotionListener(getCurrentScreen().getMouseMotionListener());
            if(getCurrentScreen().getKeyListener() != null) removeKeyListener(getCurrentScreen().getKeyListener());
        //      if(currentScreen.getMouseWheelListener() != null) removeMouseWheelListener(currentScreen.getMouseWheelListener());
        }
    }

    private void addListeners(){
        if(getCurrentScreen() != null){
            if(getCurrentScreen().getMouseListener() != null)addMouseListener(getCurrentScreen().getMouseListener());
            if(getCurrentScreen().getMouseMotionListener() != null) addMouseMotionListener(getCurrentScreen().getMouseMotionListener());
            if(getCurrentScreen().getKeyListener() != null){
                addKeyListener(getCurrentScreen().getKeyListener());
            }
        //      if(currentScreen.getMouseWheelListener() != null) addMouseWheelListener(currentScreen.getMouseWheelListener());
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(getCurrentScreen().getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            getCurrentScreen().update();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
                repaint();
                revalidate();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return currentScreen;
    }
    public void setCurrentScreen(Screen currentScreen) {
        this.currentScreen = currentScreen;
    }

}
```

This is how a game would start:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


import game.mainScreenTeam.Dragon;
import game.mainScreenTeam.HomeScreen;
import game.miniGameTeam.GameInstructions;
import game.miniGameTeam.GameScreen;
import game.miniGameTeam.HighScoreScreen;
import game.shopScreen.BuyScreenWendy;
import game.shopScreen.HomeShopScreen;
import game.shopScreen.SellShopZheng;

import guiPractice.GUIApplication;
import guiPractice.Screen;
import guiPractice.components.AnimatedComponent;

/**
 * @author Kat
 *
 */
public class DragonLand extends GUIApplication {

    public static DragonLand game;
    public static int coins = 1500; 
    public static HomeScreen homeScreen;
    public static Screen shopMain; // shop 1
    public static Screen sellScreen; // shop 2
    public static Screen buyScreen; // shop 3
    public static Screen highscoreScreen; // high score
    public static GameScreen miniGameScreen; // minigame
    public static Screen gameInstructionsScreen;
    public static Screen HelpScreen;
    public static Color NAVY;
    public static Color BRIGHT_PINK;
    public static Color LIGHT_PINK;
    public static Color LIGHT_NUDE;
    public static Color DARKER_NUDE;


    /**
     * 
     */
//  public static void addDragon(AnimatedComponent a){
//      dragonList.add(a);
//  }
    public DragonLand() {

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see guiPractice.GUIApplication#initScreen()
     */
    @Override
    protected void initScreen() {
        initColors();


        miniGameScreen = new GameScreen(getWidth(),getHeight());
        shopMain = new HomeShopScreen(getWidth(),getHeight());
        sellScreen = new SellShopZheng(getWidth(),getHeight());
        homeScreen = new HomeScreen(getWidth(),getHeight());
        buyScreen = new BuyScreenWendy(getWidth(),getHeight());
        highscoreScreen = new HighScoreScreen(getWidth(),getHeight());
        HomeScreen.jenCode = new game.mainScreenTeam.HomeJenniber();
        gameInstructionsScreen = new GameInstructions(getWidth(), getHeight());

        setScreen(homeScreen);


    }
    private void initColors() {
        NAVY = new Color(62,74,99);
        BRIGHT_PINK = new Color(224,102,102);
        LIGHT_PINK = new Color(248,186,182);
        LIGHT_NUDE = new Color(244,215,183);
        DARKER_NUDE = new Color(230,195,147);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game = new DragonLand();
        Thread go = new Thread(game);
        go.start();
    }

    //public coin getter + setter
        public void setCoins(int x){
            coins = x;
        }
        public int getCoins(){
            return coins;
        }

}
```

This is the home screen

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import game.DragonLand;
import guiPractice.ClickableScreen;
import guiPractice.components.Action;
import guiPractice.components.AnimatedComponent;
import guiPractice.components.Button;
import guiPractice.components.Graphic;
import guiPractice.components.TextLabel;
import guiPractice.components.Visible;
import guiPractice.sampleGames.MouseFollower;

/**
 * @author Kat 
 * @author Jenniber
 *
 */
public class HomeScreen extends ClickableScreen implements Runnable{

    private Graphic background;
    public static HomeJenniber jenCode;

    public HomeScreen(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
        Thread play = new Thread(this);
        play.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void initAllObjects(ArrayList<Visible> viewObjects) {

        background=new Graphic(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),"img/Grassland.png");
        viewObjects.add(background);
        HomeKat katCode=new HomeKat(viewObjects, getWidth(), getHeight());

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

}
```

katCode adds buttons to the screen and image annimations

Comment: what is the exception or issue?

Comment: no exception or issue, just screen doesn't update unless I resize the window manually

Answer (score 2):

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(getCurrentScreen().getImage(), 0, 0, null);
}
```

Don't override paint() on a JFrame.

The proper way to do custom painting is to override `paintComponent(...)` on a `JPanel` (or JComponent) and then you can set the content pane of the frame to this panel. And don't forget to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement in the method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

However if you do get lazy, then at minimum you need to invoke `super.paint`(...) as the first statement in the paint(...) method.

Also, I doubt you need the revalidate(), since you don't appear to be adding/removing components from the frame.

But in general the order should be:

```
revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
repaint(); // paint components in new location.
```

I also don't know why you are invoking the update() method. That seems like old AWT code which you don't use in Swing. I suggest you take a look at the tutorial link I gave you and look at the table of contents for other Swing basics.

Comment: the update() method is for screens since that method needs to be called. Also I tried adding super.paint() like you suggested, but it didn't seem to work. In fact, now the screen doesn't show anything at all. Also, I'm taking AP Java so this specific class was made with my teacher in class

Comment: @Ksemenova, well we don't know what the Screen class does. All I know is your code is wrong. If you override paint() then super.paint() should be the first statement otherwise you lose Swing functionality because you don't invoke some painting logic. We also don't know how you start the application or start your Thread. To many unknowns to give specify help.

Comment: thank you for your help, sorry I didn't make the post clearer, I just added the screen code and the create game code above. Let me know if you see anything. It is just strange that on a mac it doesn't run yet on a PC it does.

Comment: @Ksemenova, your code has way too many custom classes for me to get an idea of what you are doing. `It is just strange that on a mac it doesn't run yet on a PC it does.` - no it is not strange. You a breaking Swing painting conventions by not invoking super.paint(...). The paint() method is responsible for buffering and so on. You may get different results on different platforms because each platform may do the painting slightly different. So when you break the rules you get random results.